# pdfTeX error even when file exists: cannot open Type 1 font file (MinionPro-Disp.pfb for reading

Tags: classicthesis, minionpro

I am using the classicthesis template with MinionPro. The MinionPro font files are installed (MiKTeX 2.9) and work with other documents. However, the system complains that MinionPro-Disp.pfb file does not exist and yet it is present in the TeX font file structure. I did the database refresh, checked that Map MionPro is set in the updmap.cfg. 
Some font files for MinionPro are correctly found. See below extract from the log file:

```
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ae.enc}
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ab.enc}
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ac.enc}   
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-aa.enc}
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file MinionPro-Disp.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The file has attribute A, is not hidden and can be read, according to the explorer in Windows 7, same as the other .pfb files in the `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\pfm\adobe\MinionPro` directory.
Any idea why this is so and how I should correct it?
Thanks.

Comment: The .pfb files should be in `…\fonts\type1\Adobe\MinionPro`

Comment: @Bernard Please, add an answer

Answer (score 2):

`.pfm` files are (Windows-specific) metric files (on other systems, they're `.afm` files). The `.pfb` files, which contain the description of each character in a font, as all additions to the system, are to be placed in a `texmf roots` that is distinct from the texmf root of the distribution, say `TeXMF-local`.

As you're under MiKTeX, this local root is not defined by default, so you have to define one, if you didn't already do it. That is done through `MiKTeX Settings`, a.k.a `MiKTeX Options`, `Roots` tab, `Add…` button (as administrator if you want all users to have access to the font).

You should not install whatever in the system root (in your case `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\`, because it may be erased on updates. As Minion Pro is not part of the distribution; `.pfb`s should go to `…\TeXMF-local\ Fonts\type1\Adobe\ MinionPro\`, and similarly for `.tfm, .vf, .map, .enc` files. You also should have a local or a personal `updmap.cfg` where Minion Pro is mentioned, which has to be put in `TeXMF-local\miktek\config` (for all users) or in `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config` for a personal installation.

Finally you will have to refresh the FNDB (via MiKTeX Options) and run `updmap` from the console, to refresh the type 1 fonts databases (`dvips.map` anf the like).